# Xamarin forms changing fontawesome icon through binding and converter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I added to my AssemblyInfo some font-awqesome fonts.
Now, I want to change from one star to another solid star on click (toggle).
I have a star `&#xf005;`

And I added converter:

```
 public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public string TrueValue { get; set; }
        public string FalseValue { get; set; }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var valueAsBool = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

            return valueAsBool ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only one way bindings are supported with this converter");
        }
    }
```

My XAML code with this Label looks like:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:BoolToStringConverter 
                x:Key="colorConverter"
                TrueValue="#0275BA"
                FalseValue="#949494"/>
            <converter:BoolToStringConverter 
                x:Key="fontFamilyConverter"
                TrueValue="FA-S"
                FalseValue="FA-R"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
...
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectItems}">
...
<Label FontSize="Medium" FontFamily="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource fontFamilyConverter}}" TextColor="{Binding IsFavorite, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}" Text="{StaticResource IconStar}">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ToggleFavoriteObjectCommand, Mode=TwoWay, Source={x:Reference Page}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
...
</ListView>
```

I have i List => `ObjectItems`. each item in list has information is item favorite or not - if is, then change FontFamily to FontAwesomeSolid, if not, then the FontFamily is FontAwesomeRegular.

I implemented my VM:

```
public class SearchObjectsViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SearchObjectsViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(async () => { await GetObjectInstancesList(); });
        ToggleFavoriteObjectCommand = new Command(async(data) => await ToggleFavoriteObjects(data));
    }


public ICommand ToggleFavoriteObjectCommand { get; set; }
ObservableCollection<CustomPin> _objectItems { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<CustomPin> ObjectItems
{
    get
    {
        return _objectItems;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_objectItems != value)
        {
            _objectItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjectItems));
        }
    }
}

//GettingDataFromApi
private async Task GetObjectInstancesList()
{
  ObjectItems = new ObservableCollection<CustomPin>();

  var objectsResponse = await ApiServiceProvider.GetObjectInstances();
}

//OnClick OnTheIcon
private async Task ToggleFavoriteObjects(object objectId)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(objectId);
    ObjectItems.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(c => { c.IsFavorite = !c.IsFavorite; return c; }).ToList();
}

}
```

So, convert works on loading initial data, some pins are solid (have filled-in color), someones dont.
But my issue is on click on the pin, I send to my viewmodel id of that pin through shell passing parameter, it catches, go to method `ToggleFavoriteObjects` with correct `objectId` then it **updates** my ObservableCollection list, but on my ui nothing really happens?

Why?

Comment: try setting your listView.ItemSource to null and then reassign new values to it. There is an issue with Xamarin forms and ListView not updating values visually if the item count doesnt change.